# How to run sh script after beanstalk deploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a spring boot application that runs on beanstalk.

Since it's conencted to a keycloak server, i need to install it's certificate.

i've done it directly in the ec2 instance, but since the environement is transient, i need to make it automatic after each new deploy or instance initialisation.

How can i do that, if .ebextensions makes this possible, how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using `.ebextensions` should work.

Per the [Advanced environment customization with configuration files (.ebextensions)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76191021/how-to-run-sh-script-after-beanstalk-deploy), if you create `.ebextensions` at the root of your project repository and place configuration scripts in it with names ending in `.config`, Beanstalk will run these scripts as part of each deployment.

Note that:

1. A `.config` script must use the Beanstalk-specific configuration syntax.
2. Beanstalk runs scripts in alphabetical order an doesn't care what file names you use as long as they end in `.config`
3. Beanstalk runs the scripts as part of each deployment *before* it launches your application... which I think is exactly what you want in order to avoid a "file not found" exception from your Spring Boot app being started before the certificate has been created.

Beanstalk supports a number of different directives in a Beanstalk config file, but I think you'll only need `files:` and `command:` to get things working.

I created the example config file below for you:

```yaml
# .ebextensions/01_install_keycloak_cert.config

files:
  "/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/keycloak.crt":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: "root"
    group: "root"
    content: |
      -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
      <insert certificate here>
      -----END CERTIFICATE-----

commands:
  01_update_ca_trust:
    command: update-ca-trust extract
```

Note that I have not worked with Keycloak or tested this solution, but I *did* base it off of the information below:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-files
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-commands
- https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/security_guide/sec-securing_dns_traffic_with_dnssec#sec-Security_Guide-Understanding_trust_anchors